# JavaScript filter array function

Tags: javascript

I've made a list of ships that it represented like so:

```
var fleet = 
    ["RMS MARY", 2000, 15],
    ["TITANIC 2", 10000, 13],
    ["Boaty McBoatface", 2000, 18],
    ["Jutlandia", 1945, 10], 
    ["Hjejlen", 250, 8] 
];
```

I want to write a function that will filter the ships by a given capacity.
Example:

```
filterByCapacity(fleet,5000)
```

This should only return the ship `Titanic 2` since it is the only ship with a capacity higher than `5000`.
Any ideas on how to write such a function?

Comment: Even your `fleet` array is misconstructed.

Answer (score 1):

Easy :

```
function filterByCapacity(fleet, capacity) {
    var filteredArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < fleet.length; i++) {
        // Supposing we know that the capacity is the second index in the array
        if (fleet[i][1] >= capacity)    // Or you can make this strictly greather than (>)
            filteredArray.push(fleet[i]);
    }
    return (filteredArray);
}
```

But I suggest you use objects rather than arrays. Something more like this :

```
var fleet = [
    {
        name: "RMS MARY",
        capacity: 2000,
        age: 15,  // I had no idea what the third index meant so I made up one
    },
    {
        name: "TITANIC 2",
        capacity: 10000,
        age: 13,
    },
    {
        name: "Boaty McBoatface",
        capacity: 2000,
        age: 18,
    },
    {
        name: "Jutlandia",
        capacity: 1945,
        age: 10,
    },
    {
        name: "Hjejlen",
        capacity: 250,
        age: 8,
    }
];
```

That way you can make one generic function `filterBy(fleet, paramName, paramValue)` that could return you the ships that match the filter

Comment: "function filterByCapacity(fleet, capacity) {
    var filteredArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < fleet.length; i++) {
        // Supposing we know that the capacity is the second index in the array
        if (fleet[i][1] >= capacity)    // Or you can make this strictly greather than (>)
            filteredArray.push(fleet[i]);
    }
    return (filteredArray);
}"

This code works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: @MathiasV.Jensen It's not the most efficient solution though. Using `Array.prototype.filter` (like in @ojator and my answers) is considerably faster than looping manually.

Comment: @Tobsta : Wrong ! What Array.prototype.filter actually does is looping trough the array with the additional hassle of referencing the index and the entire array for each iteration even if in your case you don't name the arguments. Note this : not because a function already exists, it is necessarily more optimized. Proof : https://embed.plnkr.co/2nuxwkEUsiWZsvuLk6Nw/

Comment: @M.Kejji `.filter` is much easier to read though - it signals that you are filtering a collection, whereas a for loop could be doing many things.

Also much better in terms of minimising side-effects and mutation.

Comment: @otajor: That's why it is a good idea to create a function for this and to call `filterByCapacity` instead of doing for loops everytime. I think you still don't realize it but what `.filter` does is exactly this : a for loop with a callback function. And since you seem to care about efficiency, the fact that `.filter` is 16 times slower should be a sufficient argument

Comment: @M.Kejji I didn't say I cared about efficiency. I care about clean code, and for loops are ugly and unclear. Filter is much clearer for someone reading your code, and unless you really need to optimise your efficiency, I still think it's preferable.

Comment: @otajor I like for loops :). And I like efficiency even more. I can make sacrifices on efficiency for beauty sometimes but here, I don't see a sufficient difference to make me choose a function that's 16 times slower. EDIT : please re-read your first comment.

Comment: @M.Kejji fair enough. I have seen plenty of people who think that higher-order functions are faster than loops, so definitely worth pointing out that it's not the case.

Comment: @M.Kejji Oh, I had no idea. I got the impression that the implementation of `.filter` was the same as the code above, and faster because it doesn't have to be interpreted before run (as it's built into the browser). But it is definitely more readable, and better code.

Comment: @Tobsta: Oops I got confused I thought it was you answering all this time. And yes I thought exactly the same as you : since it is native code, it should be faster but I learnt very recently that you can't do any asumption of this kind before trying and checking for yourself

Answer (score 1):

First, I'd like to point out that your array was badly made. You were missing a left square bracket on the first entry ("RMS MARY".) The corrected array is below:

```
var fleet = [
    ["RMS MARY", 2000, 15],
    ["TITANIC 2", 10000, 13],
    ["Boaty McBoatface", 2000, 18],
    ["Jutlandia", 1945, 10], 
    ["Hjejlen", 250, 8], 
];
```

Second, I'd recommend that you represent the ships with objects instead of arrays, so you'd have something like this:

```
var fleet = {
    {name: "RMS MARY", capacity: 2000, somethingElse: 15},
    {name: "TITANIC 2", capacity: 10000, somethingElse: 13},
    {name: "Boaty McBoatface", capacity: 2000, somethingElse: 18},
    {name: "Jutlandia", capacity: 1945, somethingElse: 10},
    {name: "Hjejlen", capacity: 250, somethingElse: 8},
};
```

Now, as for the function you want, I'll provide two, one for the original array representation of ships, and one for the object representation:

```
//array representation
function filterByCapacity(fleet, capacity){
    return fleet.filter(function(ship){
        return ship[1] >= capacity;
    });
}

//object representation
function filterByCapacity(fleet, capacity){
    return fleet.filter(function(ship){
        return ship.capacity >= capacity;
    });
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Represent your ships as objects:

```
var fleet = [
  {name: "RMS Mary", capacity: 2000, whatever: 15},
   ...
];
```

Then you can use filter in a way that is readable and makes sense.

```
function filterByCapacity(fleetArr, minCapacity) {
  return fleetArr.filter(function(ship) {
    return ship.capacity > minCapacity;
  });
}
console.log(filterByCapacity(fleet, 5000)) // only Titanic
```